# Delete Button from Form Posting

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sqldatareader, sql-delete

I have a table AVUKAT
`Columns--> HESAP, MUSTERI, AVUKAT`

This is my delete button code

```
protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerCstr"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            myConnection.Open();


            string hesap = Label1.Text;
            string musteriadi = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
            string avukat = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM AVUKAT WHERE (@HESAP, @MUSTERI, @AVUKAT)", myConnection);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HESAP", hesap);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MUSTERI", musteriadi);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVUKAT", avukat);
            cmd.Connection = myConnection;

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            Grid_Goster.DataSource = dr;
            Grid_Goster.Visible = true;
            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

But it generates an error like this.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
Source Error:
Line 83:             cmd.Connection = myConnection;
Line 84: 
Line 85:             SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
Line 86:             Grid_Goster.DataSource = dr;
Line 87:             Grid_Goster.Visible = true;
```

I can't find the error..
Where is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql command currently is `DELETE FROM AVUKAT WHERE (@HESAP, @MUSTERI, @AVUKAT)`

This needs to be changed to be a valid Delete command based on the actual table. Based on what you wrote above, it would need to be:

```
DELETE FROM AVUKAT 
WHERE HESAP = @HESAP AND 
      MUSTERI = @MUSTERI AND 
      AVUKAT = @AVUKAT
```

Comment: Very true.. in addition you better Dispose the connection and Command after using it.

Comment: Yes, that would be a good thing to do. But that is not what is causing this error.

Comment: Thanks, it works correctly. But now there is another error like "Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'Gridview1'" But there is no DataSource property :s I'm confused..

Comment: Post a new question with your GridView markup and the error message

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is wrong, you haven't given a boolean condition to specify which rows should be deleted.

If you wanted to delete based on all of those parameters being true:

```
DELETE FROM AVUKAT 
WHERE HESAP = @HESAP
AND MUSTERI = @MUSTERI 
AND AVUKAT = @AVUKAT
```

Or if you wanted to delete based on any one of those parameters being true:

```
DELETE FROM AVUKAT 
WHERE HESAP = @HESAP
OR MUSTERI = @MUSTERI 
OR AVUKAT = @AVUKAT
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to provide boolean expressions in your SQL statement. For example:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM AVUKAT WHERE @HESAP = 'foobar' AND @MUSTERI > 0 AND @AVUKAT <> 42")
```